# Using natural keys with entity code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

So, I'm using Entity Framework and need to now how set my own primary key.

Im using the [Key] data annotation but when I persist the entity that field is autogenerated even having that I previously set that property.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that in your [Key] Attribute you need to specify the DatabaseGeneratedOption as follows:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DataBaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```